# How to display, the percentage price promotion sub-category in Category View

Tags: magento

In the category we have subcategories as thumbnails. In the corner, I would like to show the maximum percentage discount was from this sub-category.
To script chosen the best percentage and it display a in Category Overview
Today I wanted to do but I can not get into some of the data inside categories.

```
<?php
    $_Percent = 100 - round(($_product->getFinalPrice()) / $_product->getPrice() *100);
    $arrTest = array($_Percent);
    $array[] = $_Percent;
    $var = (max(($array)));
    $_SESSION['globalprice'.$currentCategoryId.''] = $var;
?>
```

This code is placed in the file `list.phtml` and works but only when I open subacategories. But `view.phtml` where display categories view not working.

---

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-4-col">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <?php
    $_Percent = 100 - round(($_product->getFinalPrice()) / $_product->getPrice() *100);
    $arrTest = array($_Percent);
    $array[] = $_Percent;   
    $var =  (max(($array)));
    $_SESSION['globalprice'.$currentCategoryId.''] = $var; 
    ?>
```

This code is placed in the file `list.phtml` and works but only when I open subacategories. But `view.phtml` where display categories view not working. Thats clear because I made this by session for test but when i try create this same code I cant get access for summary product value from category view.

Comment: What have you tried?  We need to see the code you've written in order to help you.

Comment: @dESIGNEz - Please edit your question rather than put code in a comment.